# search/filter component for angular2 datatables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have developed a paginating datatable component in my angular2 application with the help of this git code: https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable

To achieve search/filter functionality for this I have created a pipe and passed it to template as below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data | filterPipe: searchTerm">
```

Search is working fine but the pagination at the bottom of the page is not updated. I think this will work if I can update 'data'. Can I get any suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the filter directly on [mfData] as code below.

```html
<table class="table table-striped" [mfData]="(singleData | search:searchText)" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="10">

.
.
.
</table>
```